# tab is not getting clicked in protractor

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, selenium, protractor

This is my full html of Tab section

```
<tab heading="Meta Data" id="heading_meta-data">
                                <div id="meta-data" class="row">

                                <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3">
                                <!-- output -->
                                <div class="box box-default">
                                 <div class="box-header with-border">
                                   <h6 class="box-title">Sensor Output</h6>
                                   <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                                     <button class="btn btn-box-tool" ng-model="outputCollapsed" ng-click="outputCollapsed=!outputCollapsed"><i ng-show="!outputCollapsed" class="fa fa-plus"></i><i ng-show="outputCollapsed" class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>

                                   </div><!-- /.box-tools -->
                                 </div><!-- /.box-header -->
                                 <div ng-show="outputCollapsed" class="box-body">
                                   <!-- show ouput fields here -->
                                   <!-- output field box starts here -->


                                <div ng-repeat="outpt in sensorDetails.metaData.output" class="box box-default">

                                 <div class="box-header with-border">
                                   <h6 class="box-title">{{outpt.name}}</h6>
                                   <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                                     <button class="btn btn-box-tool" ng-model="ocollapsed" ng-click="ocollapsed=!ocollapsed"><i ng-show="!ocollapsed" class="fa fa-plus"></i><i ng-show="ocollapsed" class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>

                                   </div><!-- /.box-tools -->
                                 </div><!-- /.box-header -->
                                 <div ng-show="ocollapsed" class="box-body">
                                   <!-- ouput fields details -->
                                   <ul>

                                <li><b>name</b> : <small>{{outpt.name}}</small></li>

                                <li><b>type </b> : <small>{{outpt.type}}</small></li>

                                <li><b>unit </b> : <small>{{outpt.unit}}</small></li>
                                   </ul>
                                 </div><!-- /.box-body -->
                                </div><!-- /.box -->
                                   <!-- output field box ends here -->


                                 </div><!-- /.box-body -->
                                </div><!-- /.box -->
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3">
                                <!-- parameter -->
                                <div class="box box-default">
                                 <div class="box-header with-border">
                                   <h6 class="box-title">parameter</h6>
                                   <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                                     <button class="btn btn-box-tool" ng-model="parameterCollapsed" ng-click="parameterCollapsed=!parameterCollapsed"><i ng-show="!parameterCollapsed" class="fa fa-plus"></i><i ng-show="parameterCollapsed" class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>

                                   </div><!-- /.box-tools -->
                                 </div><!-- /.box-header -->
                                 <div ng-show="parameterCollapsed" class="box-body">


                                <!-- parameter field box starts here -->


                                <div ng-repeat="param in sensorDetails.metaData.parameter" class="box box-default">

                                 <div class="box-header with-border">
                                   <h6 class="box-title">{{param.name}}</h6>
                                   <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                                     <button class="btn btn-box-tool" ng-model="pcollapsed" ng-click="pcollapsed=!pcollapsed"><i ng-show="!pcollapsed" class="fa fa-plus"></i><i ng-show="pcollapsed" class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>

                                   </div><!-- /.box-tools -->
                                 </div><!-- /.box-header -->
                                 <div ng-show="pcollapsed" class="box-body">
                                   <!-- ouput fields details -->
                                   <ul>

                                <li><b>name</b> : <small>{{param.name}}</small></li>

                                <li><b>value</b> : <small>{{param.value}}</small></li>

                                <li><b>type </b> : <small>{{param.type}}</small></li>

                                <li><b>unit </b> : <small>{{param.unit}}</small></li>
                                   </ul>
                                 </div><!-- /.box-body -->
                                </div><!-- /.box -->

                                <!-- parameter field box ends here -->


                                 </div><!-- /.box-body -->
                                </div><!-- /.box -->
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3">
                                <!-- identifier -->
                                <div class="box box-default">
                                 <div class="box-header with-border">
                                   <h6 class="box-title">identifier</h6>
                                   <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                                     <button class="btn btn-box-tool" ng-model="identifierCollapsed" ng-click="identifierCollapsed=!identifierCollapsed"><i ng-show="!identifierCollapsed" class="fa fa-plus"></i><i ng-show="identifierCollapsed" class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>

                                   </div><!-- /.box-tools -->
                                 </div><!-- /.box-header -->
                                 <div ng-show="identifierCollapsed" class="box-body">


                                <!-- identifier field box starts here -->


                                <div ng-repeat="iden in sensorDetails.metaData.identifier" class="box box-default">

                                 <div class="box-header with-border">
                                   <h6 class="box-title">{{iden.name}}</h6>
                                   <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                                     <button class="btn btn-box-tool" ng-model="icollapsed" ng-click="icollapsed=!icollapsed"><i ng-show="!icollapsed" class="fa fa-plus"></i><i ng-show="icollapsed" class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>

                                   </div><!-- /.box-tools -->
                                 </div><!-- /.box-header -->
                                 <div ng-show="icollapsed" class="box-body">
                                   <!-- ouput fields details -->
                                   <ul>

                                <li><b>name</b> : <small>{{iden.name}}</small></li>

                                <li><b>value</b> : <small>{{iden.value}}</small></li>

                                <li><b>type </b> : <small>{{iden.type}}</small></li>

                                <li><b>unit </b> : <small>{{iden.unit}}</small></li>
                                   </ul>
                                 </div><!-- /.box-body -->
                                </div><!-- /.box -->

                                <!-- identifier field box ends here -->

                                 </div><!-- /.box-body -->
                                </div><!-- /.box -->
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3">
                                <!-- classifier -->
                                <div class="box box-default">
                                 <div class="box-header with-border">
                                   <h6 class="box-title">classifier</h6>
                                   <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                                     <button class="btn btn-box-tool" ng-model="collapsed" ng-click="classifierCollapsed=!classifierCollapsed"><i ng-show="!classifierCollapsed" class="fa fa-plus"></i><i ng-show="classifierCollapsed" class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>

                                   </div><!-- /.box-tools -->
                                 </div><!-- /.box-header -->
                                 <div ng-show="classifierCollapsed" class="box-body">

                                 <!-- classifier field box starts here -->


                                <div ng-repeat="classi in sensorDetails.metaData.classifier" class="box box-default">

                                 <div class="box-header with-border">
                                   <h6 class="box-title">{{classi.name}}</h6>
                                   <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                                     <button class="btn btn-box-tool" ng-model="pcollapsed" ng-click="ccollapsed=!ccollapsed"><i ng-show="!ccollapsed" class="fa fa-plus"></i><i ng-show="ccollapsed" class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>

                                   </div><!-- /.box-tools -->
                                 </div><!-- /.box-header -->
                                 <div ng-show="ccollapsed" class="box-body">
                                   <!-- classifiers fields details -->
                                   <ul>

                                <li><b>name</b> : <small>{{classi.name}}</small></li>

                                <li><b>value</b> : <small>{{classi.value}}</small></li>

                                <li><b>type </b> : <small>{{classi.type}}</small></li>

                                <li><b>unit </b> : <small>{{classi.unit}}</small></li>
                                   </ul>
                                 </div><!-- /.box-body -->
                                </div><!-- /.box -->

                                <!-- classifier field box ends here -->

                                 </div><!-- /.box-body -->
                                </div><!-- /.box -->
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3">
                                <!-- capability -->
                                <div class="box box-default">
                                 <div class="box-header with-border">
                                   <h6 class="box-title">capability</h6>
                                   <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                                     <button class="btn btn-box-tool" ng-model="collapsed" ng-click="capabilityCollapsed=!capabilityCollapsed"><i ng-show="!capabilityCollapsed" class="fa fa-plus"></i><i ng-show="capabilityCollapsed" class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>

                                   </div><!-- /.box-tools -->
                                 </div><!-- /.box-header -->
                                 <div ng-show="capabilityCollapsed" class="box-body">



                                <!-- capability field box starts here -->


                                <div ng-repeat="capab in sensorDetails.metaData.capability" class="box box-default">

                                 <div class="box-header with-border">
                                   <h6 class="box-title">{{capab.name}}</h6>
                                   <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                                     <button class="btn btn-box-tool" ng-model="cacollapsed" ng-click="cacollapsed=!cacollapsed"><i ng-show="!cacollapsed" class="fa fa-plus"></i><i ng-show="cacollapsed" class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>

                                   </div><!-- /.box-tools -->
                                 </div><!-- /.box-header -->
                                 <div ng-show="cacollapsed" class="box-body">
                                   <!-- classifiers fields details -->
                                   <ul>

                                <li><b>name</b> : <small>{{capab.name}}</small></li>

                                <li><b>value</b> : <small>{{capab.value}}</small></li>

                                <li><b>type </b> : <small>{{capab.type}}</small></li>

                                <li><b>unit </b> : <small>{{capab.unit}}</small></li>
                                   </ul>
                                 </div><!-- /.box-body -->
                                </div><!-- /.box -->

                                <!-- capability field box ends here -->

                                 </div><!-- /.box-body -->
                                </div><!-- /.box -->
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3">
                                <!-- characteristics -->
                                <div class="box box-default">
                                 <div class="box-header with-border">
                                   <h6 class="box-title">characteristics</h6>
                                   <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                                     <button class="btn btn-box-tool" ng-model="characteristicsCollapsed" ng-click="characteristicsCollapsed=!characteristicsCollapsed"><i ng-show="!characteristicsCollapsed" class="fa fa-plus"></i><i ng-show="characteristicsCollapsed" class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>

                                   </div><!-- /.box-tools -->
                                 </div><!-- /.box-header -->
                                 <div ng-show="characteristicsCollapsed" class="box-body">



                                <!-- characteristics field box starts here -->


                                <div ng-repeat="char in sensorDetails.metaData.characteristics" class="box box-default">

                                 <div class="box-header with-border">
                                   <h6 class="box-title">{{char.name}}</h6>
                                   <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                                     <button class="btn btn-box-tool" ng-model="chcollapsed" ng-click="chcollapsed=!chcollapsed"><i ng-show="!chcollapsed" class="fa fa-plus"></i><i ng-show="chcollapsed" class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>

                                   </div><!-- /.box-tools -->
                                 </div><!-- /.box-header -->
                                 <div ng-show="chcollapsed" class="box-body">
                                   <!-- classifiers fields details -->
                                   <ul>

                                <li><b>name</b> : <small>{{char.name}}</small></li>

                                <li><b>value</b> : <small>{{char.value}}</small></li>

                                <li><b>type </b> : <small>{{char.type}}</small></li>

                                <li><b>unit </b> : <small>{{char.unit}}</small></li>
                                   </ul>
                                 </div><!-- /.box-body -->
                                </div><!-- /.box -->

                                <!-- characteristics field box ends here -->


                                 </div><!-- /.box-body -->
                                </div><!-- /.box -->
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3">
                                <!-- interface -->
                                <div class="box box-default">
                                 <div class="box-header with-border">
                                   <h6 class="box-title">interface</h6>
                                   <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                                     <button class="btn btn-box-tool" ng-model="interfaceCollapsed" ng-click="interfaceCollapsed=!interfaceCollapsed"><i ng-show="!interfaceCollapsed" class="fa fa-plus"></i><i ng-show="interfaceCollapsed" class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>

                                   </div><!-- /.box-tools -->
                                 </div><!-- /.box-header -->
                                 <div ng-show="interfaceCollapsed" class="box-body">



                                <!-- interface field box starts here -->


                                <div ng-repeat="intrface in sensorDetails.metaData.capability" class="box box-default">

                                 <div class="box-header with-border">
                                   <h6 class="box-title">{{intrface.name}}</h6>
                                   <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                                     <button class="btn btn-box-tool" ng-model="incollapsed" ng-click="incollapsed=!incollapsed"><i ng-show="!incollapsed" class="fa fa-plus"></i><i ng-show="incollapsed" class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>

                                   </div><!-- /.box-tools -->
                                 </div><!-- /.box-header -->
                                 <div ng-show="incollapsed" class="box-body">
                                   <!-- interface fields details -->
                                   <ul>

                                <li><b>name</b> : <small>{{intrface.name}}</small></li>

                                <li><b>value</b> : <small>{{intrface.value}}</small></li>

                                <li><b>type </b> : <small>{{intrface.type}}</small></li>

                                <li><b>unit </b> : <small>{{intrface.unit}}</small></li>
                                   </ul>
                                 </div><!-- /.box-body -->
                                </div><!-- /.box -->

                                <!-- interface field box ends here -->


                                 </div><!-- /.box-body -->
                                </div><!-- /.box -->
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3">
                                <!-- position global -->
                                <div class="box box-default">
                                 <div class="box-header with-border">
                                   <h6 class="box-title">position global</h6>
                                   <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                                     <button class="btn btn-box-tool" ng-model="positionGlobalCollapsed" ng-click="positionGlobalCollapsed=!positionGlobalCollapsed"><i ng-show="!positionGlobalCollapsed" class="fa fa-plus"></i><i ng-show="positionGlobalCollapsed" class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>

                                   </div><!-- /.box-tools -->
                                 </div><!-- /.box-header -->
                                 <div ng-show="positionGlobalCollapsed" class="box-body">


                                <ul>

                                <li><b>altitude</b> : <small>{{sensorDetails.metaData.position_global.altitude}}</small></li>

                                <li><b>latitude</b> : <small>{{sensorDetails.metaData.position_global.location.lat}}</small></li>

                                <li><b>longitude </b> : <small>{{sensorDetails.metaData.position_global.location.lon}}</small></li>

                                </ul>

                                 </div><!-- /.box-body -->
                                </div><!-- /.box -->
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                </tab>
```

In spec.js

```
var metaData = element(by.id('heading_meta-data')).click();
browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(metaData), 500);
metaData.click();
```

here the tab is not getting clicked..............

Please tell what could be the issue.............??????????

already increased  the browser wait time but still no help.................................?????????

Comment: Do you get any errors when you run it? or just the click doesn't perform and execution continues?

Comment: no errors..........but execution doesn't happen

Comment: So, you are trying to click the whole tab element which has so many sub-elements in it? Or is there an element that you want to click in particular inside tab? If its the whole element that you want to  click, then i dont see any sense in it or you can probably tell us why you want to click the tab element. Thanks

Comment: I am trying to click the tab header which opens the tab content

Comment: Remove the `click()` method from `var metaData`. `browser.wait()` doesn't know what to wait for.

Comment: then how to do it....
var metaData = element(by.id('heading_meta-data'));
  browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(metaData), 10000)
  .then(function(){
   metaData.click();
  });

Answer (score 0):

Wait for the presence of tab in the DOM using `wait()` function and then try to click it once the element is found. If the element is taking longer to be displayed, then increase the timeout in the wait() function. Here's how -

```
var metaData = element(by.id('heading_meta-data'));
browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(metaData), 10000)
.then(function(){
    metaData.click();
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you share your complete html? Your tab element has a width and height greater than zero when it displays on the webpage right? Also is it in the view or its out of view when the page opens?